# for of loop in javascript to create uppercased strings

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = ["new", "name", "need"]

for (let item of arr) {
  item.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(arr)            /// [ 'new', 'name', 'need' ]
```

I am trying to create an array of UpperCased items using for of loop. However I keep getting the same array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not using that upperCase value, you are simply uppercasing it, Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toUpperCase` returns a new string, it does not change the string in place.

```js
let arr = ["new", "name", "need"]
const newArr = []
for (let item of arr) {
  newArr.push(item.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(newArr)
```

You can also do the same without an explicit loop using `map`

```js
let arr = ["new", "name", "need"]
const newArr = arr.map(item => item.toUpperCase())
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because although you change the value of the array item to upper case, you never set the item back in the array.

This code will *not* change the original array item, but will rather create a new string that is uppercase:

```
item.toUpperCase();
```

Instead, loop through the array and set the array item to the upper case version like this:

```js
let arr = ["new", "name", "need", "test"]

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i].toUpperCase();
}

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assinging that value anywhere. You have to assign it somewhere.

```js
let arr = ["new", "name", "need"]
let updatedArr = [];

for (let item of arr) {
  const value = item.toUpperCase();
  updatedArr.push(value);
}

console.log(updatedArr)
```

or simplyfied solution with `map()`:

```js
const arr = ["new", "name", "need"]
const updatedArr = arr.map(item=>item.toUpperCase());
console.log(updatedArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

`toUpperCase` **returns** an uppercased version of a string. It doesn't mutate the existing string.

You need to assign the return value somewhere.

```js
let arr = ["new", "name", "need"]

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i].toUpperCase();
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ["new", "name", "need"];
    
arr = arr.map(item => {
   return item.toUpperCase();
});
    
console.log(arr);
```